# Vertical swipe detection

Tags: java, android

Такая задача что требуется  отследить swipe верх у вью в горизонтальном viewpager. Как отследить swipe вверх у вью?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что максимально примитивное исполнение отслеживания жеста «swipe» (пролистывать?) будет иметь вид:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
        };
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            curX = event.getX();
            curY = event.getY();
            float defX = x - curX;
            if ((y - curY) > Math.abs(defX)) {
                /*Your action*/
            } else {
                int curItem = view.getCurrentItem();
                int allItem = ADAPTER.getCount();
                if (defX < 0) if (curItem < allItem - 1) view.setCurrentItem(curItem + 1, true);
                if (defX > 0) if (curItem > 0) view.setCurrentItem(curItem - 1, true);
            };
            x = curX;
            y = curY;
        };
        return true;
    };
});
```

Если палец пользователя двигается вверх быстрее, чем влево или вправо, то жест, я считаю, можно считать пролистыванием вверх.

Прописными буквами выделена неиспользованная ранее переменная - адаптер для ViewPager. `float x, y, curX, curY` должны быть объявлены вне методов жизненного цикла, чтобы были видны в `onTouch`.

P.S. Я впервые работаю с ViewPager, поэтому могут быть неточности в исполнении, но, надеюсь, логика ясна.